# How to match regex patterns that contain special characters?

Tags: php, regex

I have a generic routine which used to substitute out short-codes (which begin with a "^" character) with gender specific options. I have been asked to extend this to correct some common misspellings. These words won't have a special character at the start.

Until now I have been using PHP's `str_replace` function but because of the possibility of some words appearing within others, I need to ensure that the code uses word boundaries when matching. I am now attempting to use `preg_replace`.

While the actual code is getting data from a database table, including the gender specific replacements, I can reproduce the issue with simpler code for the purposes of asking this question.

Consider the following array with `$search => $replace` structure:

```
$subs = array("^Heshe" => "He",
   "apples" => "bananas");
```

I then want to cycle through the array to replace the tokens:

```
$message = "^Heshe likes apples but not crabapples.";
foreach ($subs as $search => $replace)
{
   $pattern = '/\b' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '\b/u';
   $message = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $message);
}
echo $message;
```

I expect the message `He likes bananas but not crabapples.` to be displayed, but instead I get the message `^Heshe likes bananas but not crabapples.`

I have also tried `$pattern = '/\b\Q' . $search . '\E\b/u'`, also with the same results.

Unfortunately, the "^" characters are part of some legacy system and changing it is not feasible. How do I get the regex to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
$pattern = '/\b' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '\b/u';
```

As `$search` is `^Heshe` you cannot match `\b` (word boundary) before `^` since that is not a word character.

You can use lookarounds instead in your pattern like this:

```
$pattern = '/(?<!\w)' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '(?!\w)/u';
```

Which means match `$search` if it is not followed and preceded by a word char.

Or else use:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=\s|^)' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '(?=\s|$)/u';
```

Which means match `$search` if it is followed and preceded by a whitespace or line start/end.

Comment: Thank you! Your first option seems to work as expected. Your second, however, does not substitute the last `apples` in this string: `$message = "^Heshe likes apples but not crabapples. He likes apples.";` because of the full stop character.

Comment: Yes that's right. My preference is also for first **negative lookahead** regex.